# How can we integrate vaadin 7.1.15 with liferay 6.2?

Tags: java, vaadin, liferay-6, vaadin7

Please explain the above one with all the needed steps?? 
When i added the vaadin 7 program to liferay portal, it showing an error in the java resources folder. So, I opened the folder and check for errors. but no errors in the inner folder.. it is showing only one error symbol in the java resources folder.

Comment: this video might help you [link]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=brPwU6uqYJA&list=UUsGakFIbOsj-fgPFLf1QlQA